# Include json object in restructured text with a drop-down menu in the output

Tags: json, jsonschema, restructuredtext

I would like to include json object in restructured text. The json object is very big (number of fields and sub fields). So I would to include a small drop down next to each {}

Json object

```
{
    "$id": "https://example.com/person.schema.json",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "Person",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "subType1": {
        "type": "object",
        "description": "A sub type with additionalProperties false.",
        "properties": {
          "subProp1": {
            "type": "number"
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      },
      "subType2": {
        "type": "object",
        "description": "A sub type with additionalProperties true.",
        "properties": {
          "subProp2": {
            "type": "number"
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": true
      },
      "anInt": {
        "type": "integer",
        "description": "This is an integer, it should not show additional properties. (issue #132)"
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": {
      "type": "object",
      "description": "additionalProperties schema.",
      "properties": {
        "propA": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The generated html should have a drop down at

properties, subType1, subtype2 etc..

Rather than presenting whole json object.  It should have a small drop down menu, so that people can navigate the required fields.

Comment: Do you intend to use Sphinx to create HTML output?

Comment: Typically on StackOverflow, it is expected that you first start building something, writing some code, etc., and then ask a question if you encounter an issue. -- What is the question? Do you want to know how to build custom directive? How to build custom output generator?

Comment: @mzjn Yes, I am using sphinx to create html

Comment: @sinoroc, I am looking for some restructured text script/code. In mark sown we use <br> tag. Now sure how it can done in restructured text, while reading the json from a file

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible. You will have to write custom directive, or a Sphinx extension.